# What is the probability of choosing the bomb?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Five crackers are put in a bowl full of bran. In four of them, there is a check for $ 2 million, one contains a bomb, strong enough to kill the person who pulls the cracker.

1. Mr. Adam and Mr. Bill reach for the bowl together. Mr. Adam opens up the lid and picks up one of the crackers. What is the probability of choosing the bomb for Mr. Adam and Mr. Bill? (It should be 1/5 for Mr. Adam and 1/5 for Mr. Bill)

$$P(X_1) =1/5$$

$$P(X_2) =P(X_2|X_1)*P(X_1) + P(X_2|¬X_1)*P(¬X_1)$$

where $X_1$ means choosing the bomb on the first turn and $X_2$ means choosing the bomb on the second turn

$$P(X_2) =0*(1/5) + (1/4)*(4/5)$$
$$P(X_2) =1/5$$
2. Mr. Adam and Mr. Bill decide to draw for turns to pick from the bowl. What are the probabilities of choosing the bomb in this case?
Let's say they toss a coin and if it comes head then Mr. Adam goes and if it comes tails then Mr. Bill. So, they could choose a bomb if they get heads and also if they get tails and the other (first mover) does not choose the bomb.
$$P(X) =P(X|H)*P(H) + P(X|T,¬X_1)*P(T)*P(¬X_1)$$
$$P(X) =(1/5)*(1/2) + (1/4)*(1/2)*(4/5)$$
$$P(X) =(1/5)$$

So, there is no difference in the probabilities of choosing the bomb whether they draw for turns or not. Am I getting it right?

Comment: Strange setting... Is it risky to ask the role of the bran in the bowl ?

Comment: If I make it a less dangerous game than the question states, say one of the boxes has money and others are empty, what is the probability that Adam gets the box with the money? You have not worked it out correctly. That probability is valid for first pick but Adam and Bill both get more chances than one to pick a box if neither of them pick the box in previous attempts.

Comment: @MathLover So what should be the correct solution then? I think I did it right.

Comment: @JeanMarie Bran has no role here. It's a bowl with bran [cereal], 4 crackers containing $, and 1 containing a bomb.

Comment: Are they each to draw **only once**, by whichever method ? It would seem prudent, considering the dangerous bomb !

Comment: @trueblueanil Thank you for pointing that out. It's not clear in the question if they draw once or not. However, drawing only once makes more sense. I wonder how would that change the solution? My calculations suggest that the probability is equal to 1/5 for both of them (the first and the second mover) in both cases.

Comment: That's right, $\frac1 5$ for both of them in both cases. Actually, you don't even need to compute if you realize that a bomb (or, say, a red ball in a line of green balls) does not have any preference for position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have two persons A and B. If person A starts *first*, the probability of A choosing a specific item should be higher than that of person B.

Probability of person A (first person) choosing a specific box $ = \frac{1}{5} + \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3}{5}$

Then probability of person B choosing the specific item $ = 1 - \frac{3}{5} = \frac{2}{5}$

In the above working, person A has probability of choosing a specific item as follows -

i) in the first chance, it is $\frac{1}{5}$

ii) gets a second chance only if fails to choose the specific item in the first chance (probability of $\frac{4}{5}$) and person B also fails to choose the item next, probability of which is $\frac{3}{4}$.

iii) is certain to choose the item if both of them fail to choose the item in their first two chances.

Now if the first person can be either of them with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ based on toss of a coin, then it is easy to see that they have equal probability of picking a specific item: $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}$.

$\big(\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{5} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{5} = \frac{1}{2} \big)$.

Comment: Oh, you have made my query to OP comprehensively redundant ! (+1)

Comment: @trueblueanil thank you. By the way I just read your comment and I agree. The first chance itself is dangerous enough, the next one is worse and I wonder why will someone even pick the 5th if first $4$ had  dollars in it? :) That is why I decided to just stay away from it.

Comment: @MathLover What if they only draw once each i.e. there are a total of 2 draws? Is the probability (1/5) for both of them in the first case? Is it also the same i.e. $((1/2)*(1/5))+((1/2)*(1/5))$ in the second case?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct in that case. For person A, it is $\frac{1}{5}$. For person B, it is $\frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{5}$. In case we are deciding by toss, it would remain the same as whoever starts, the probability is $\frac{1}{5}$.